# Difficulty setting up Mycroft

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, ssl

So I'm installing Mycroft AI on my Kali computer (Git-style). I ran build_host_setup_debian.sh without any trouble, but when I try to run dev_setup.sh I get the following error:

```
Searching for pip==7.1.2
Best match: pip 7.1.2
Processing pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
pip 7.1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/bin
Installing pip2 script to /home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/bin

Using /home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip==7.1.2
Finished processing dependencies for pip==7.1.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/lib/python2.7/site-packages /pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/lib/python2.7/site-packages /pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 38, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib /pyopenssl.py", line 53, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/home/nonroot/.virtualenvs/mycroft/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 124, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Does any of [this information](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core/issues/705) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

changing `pyOpenSSL==16.0.0` in requirements.txt to `pyOpenSSL==16.2.0` fixes this.

You need to reinstall the pip package after the change.

`pip uninstall pyOpenSSL
pip install pyOpenSSL==16.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are experiencing the issue reported here: 
https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core/issues/705

We have incorporated a fix for it with this PR:
 https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core/pull/751
Basically, this updates the version of pyOpenSSL in the requirements.txt.  This fix is in the 'dev' branch of mycroft-core right now and will move into master with release 0.8.13

After this change, you will likely have to delete the ~/.virtualenv folder and then rerun dev_setup.sh